# How to approach the ODE $y'+\sin(x+y)=\sin(x-y)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

**Example:** Solve the following ODE:

$$y'+\sin(x+y)=\sin(x-y)$$

I have tried many ways to do this, but none of them worked. It isn't exact, and it isn't linear either. What should I do to move forward?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$$y'+\sin(x+y)=\sin(x-y)$$
$$y'=\sin(x-y)-\sin(x+y)=-2\cos x \sin y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\cos x \sin y$$
$$\frac{dy}{\sin y}=-2\cos x \,dx$$
$$\csc y\, dy=-2\cos x \,dx$$
Integrating both sides, we get
$$\ln|\csc y-\cot y|=-2\sin x + c$$ where $c$ is a constant of integration.